# Power plugs in Sri Lanka

Tags: power, sri-lanka

I am about to go to Sri Lanka for a dew weeks but am unsure about the type of power sockets. I know that they have type D, G and M sockets. I will be fine with the G sockets (I have an AU-UK adaptor for that).

Would I be right in saying that in hotels, type D would be more common over type M (because type M is for higher power appliances)?

Which of type D and G would be more common?

In regards to type D sockets, I have heard (from only one source) that a type C plug will work fine with them. Is this correct? In that case I could use my Europe adaptor with the type D sockets?

This is the site I got some info from:

http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/

It says that type D sockets can take type C plugs fine, and E and F plugs but its unsafe. Why would type E and F be unsafe but C alright?

Comment: Not sure if you've gone yet, but to answer the question, "Which type is more common", I'd say type D. I lived in Sri Lanka for 10 years, and that was the most common I saw in the average home and guest house. When it comes to larger hotels, it's hit or miss on which type you'll get. Some will even give you one of each. With that said, most hotels should have a 'white box' adapter to give you, if you ask, which can take pretty  much any plug, even American ones. Because of the plug confusion in the country, these adapters are very common and sold cheaply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Europe (type C) adaptor with type D sockets.

The reason E and F plugs are unsafe with a type D socket is that the ground (earth) connection will not be made. If the manufacturer of an appliance has determined that a ground connection is necessary for a particular appliance, then it will be unsafe if used with a type D socket. This usually only applies to appliances with a metal outer case, where a loose connection inside the appliance could cause the outer case to become "hot". With a proper ground connection, the current would flow to the ground and not through the user (and would probably trip a circuit breaker too).

If you're just charging your smartphone, then you'll probably be fine with a C and a G adaptor (no ground connection is required for low-power chargers). (However, I've never been to Sri Lanka so I can't comment on the types of plugs you'll actually find.)

Comment: I will only be charging my phone so I have no need for an earth pin. However, the type C plug has no earth pin, so wouldn't that be just as unsafe as connecting types E and F to a type D socket?

Comment: No, it's only unsafe if the equipment requires an earth connection AND the socket can't provide a compatible earth connection.

Comment: Because Type C has no earth pin, does that mean every appliance using this type should be double insulated? Ie nothing using the C plug should ever require earth? Do manufacturers abide by this or are there some unsafe appliances out there that use the C plug and should have an earth connection?

Comment: Properly built equipment with a C plug will be fine. However, there are still dodgy manufacturers out there who sell illegal equipment.

Comment: So just to confirm, you are saying that it is safe to use type C plugs with type D sockets because appliances using type C plugs should never require earthing?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Here we have 230v electricity line ok. I am from SriLanka. Socket types https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS9rLELQRiWrt-JCbR8HWv3IEW1teqAAdAIIxWOhz59Eq22pJncnZIQ8XJT

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS9rLELQRiWrt-JCbR8HWv3IEW1teqAAdAIIxWOhz59Eq22pJncnZIQ8XJT

Answer (score 0):

As long as your application uses 220v electricity, you're good to go. Don't worry about the type of socket, just purchase one of these>

[image]

They are commonly called multiplugs, and cost around Rs. 100-200 here.

**Disclaimer**: I am not an expert on the safety aspects, but I use all my laptops, phones and other stuff using these, and it works fine. It has been so for the past 20 years.

Comment: The statement "Don't worry about the type of socket" and the presentation of an adapter that requires one particular type of socket don't mix well. Note that there are laptop power adapters with a ground pin (e.g., with type F plug). This adapter does not provide the ground pin to Central European devices, so they would be unsafe to be used with this adapter *if* they have aground connection.

Comment: @DCTLib  i just meant that you could buy one of these here and use it with whatever socket you have. The adapters in the picture come with two types of sockets. Square pin and Round pin. If you're not sure which one to buy, buy both. However,, if you're staying in a decent hotel, they'll be happy to give you one free. Sorry about the the eletrical wrongness; I was pointing out practical issues. As i have said, I cannot guarantee safety, but it has worked for me.

Comment: Is it possible that you are mixing up "plug" and "socket"? The adapter you have posted a photo of requires one particular type of *socket* (in the wall), and then allows to connect devices with a variety of different *plugs* to it, such as American, Australian, or central European ones. The OP Is asking for a solution that works for multiple types of *sockets*, not multiple types of *plugs*.

Answer (score 0):

Sri Lanka was using Plug Type D and have recently converted to Type G.
It is illegal to sell Type D plugged appliances in electrical shops, but some hotels and houses may still use Type D.
Best advice is to visit an "Arpico" shop and buy two Muliti Sockets Type D and Type G-it will cost around Rs 200 each.enter image description here

[image]